# Python extract data from data-set and place into a list

Tags: python, count, extract

I want to find the amount of certain number occurring in a data set, I only care about the list[2] value.

```
list = [
    ['W', 1, 1],
    ['N', 3, 4], 
    ['W', 4, 0], 
    ['W', 2, 0], 
    ['S', 3, 4]
]
```

I was thinking of extracting the list[2] from list and placing into a different list like (`sortedlist`) and using `print(sortedlist.count(4))` to count how many time "4" occurs in chosen data set.

```
sortedlist = []
for counts in list:
      sortedlist.append(counts[2])
```

Also I have another question, after the list is complete I want to input into turtle text,  Does turtle text command take variables?

Comment: From what I understood: `list[2].count(4)` should do provided you use a proper list syntax.

Comment: @Austin It doesn't seem to work as count gives me 1 but it should be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count `4`s at *third* position of every lists in list of lists:

```
>>> lst = [ ['W', 1, 1], ['N', 3, 4], ['W', 4, 0], ['W', 2, 0], ['S', 3, 4] ]
>>> sum(1 for x in lst if x[2] == 4)
2
```

*Side note*: Don't name your list as `list` as it shadows built-in.

Answer (score 0):

to count the occurrences of a specific number at a specific position in each element of the list you can use:

```
search = 4
position_in_row = 3

occurrences = 0
for el in list:
    if el[position_in_row-1] == search:
        occurrences += 1

print(occurrences)
```

I am not familiar with turtle though and would suggest to dig into the documentation or open another question.

If you are interested in each third element of each subelement try the snipped again, I edited it.